# Strange runtime issue VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have the following issue with a VB.net program I'm finishing off. Basically I have two forms. **Form1** and **techs**. Form 1 loads first and is my 'main' page. I want to reference a variable in techs on **Form1**. I publicly declared this variable as so:

```
 Public jobID As String
```

I then reference this on Form1 as so:

Dim job As String = techs.jobID

This is the error I am getting:

```
An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion.  Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using 'Me.'
```

Can anyone give me an idea of what going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the constructor for techs? i.e. the bit of code that creates an instance of your second form.

Comment: Infact thinking about it, i think the problem is the fact that the techs is referencing as variable that hasn't been constructed before it is referenced.

Comment: techs must be instantiated first

Comment: Please add the text from inner exception to your question, because I can not reproduce your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
Public jobID As String
```

to

```
Public Shared jobID As String
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate first techs

```
Dim newtechs As New techs()
```

then , assign techs.jobID to a string variable under Form1

```
Dim job As String = newtechs.jobID
```

Comment: Dim job As String = newtechs.jobID